# how to compare two string and highlight changes?

Tags: c#

I have two strings.

```
stringV1 = "123456";
stringV2 = "102300456";
```

First I need to compare them.

If `stringV2` has some changes, this new text should be highlighted like this:

```
"1'0'23'00'456"
```

Comment: asp.net, wpf, sl or windows forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this has been discussed here already sometimes...

[How to highlight the differences between subsequent lines in a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838746/how-to-highlight-the-differences-between-subsequent-lines-in-a-file)

[How to display word differences using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934159/how-to-display-word-differences-using-c)

...

Answer (score 0):

Use Diff algorithm for string comparision.